# О числительном СОРОК.

Tags: числительные

В ряде сложных числительных  двадцать, тридцать, пятьдесят, шестьдесят... вдруг числительное СОРОК, которое по форме не похоже на перечисленные числительные . Что это? Как оно образовано?

Answer (score 7):

Слово сорок связано с древнерусской мерой отсчета собольих шкурок сороками –  мешками определенного объема, в которые входили сорок шкурок. Исходное значение слова сорок – мешок, рубашка, для сравнения: сорочка. Значение единицы счета слово сорок сначала получило в речи охотников, вытеснив более древнее обозначение этого числа – четыре десяте.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, еще число 40 имело обрядовое значение, например, панихида сорокоуст на  40 дней, сорок сороков - в смысле много. 
Еще говорят так могло быть шкурка -скурка- скорок (скорняк), слово просто похоже на сорок. Выделилось потом в отдельное слово.
К сорока примыкает  и **девяносто** - тоже выпадает из ряда. объяснения сомнительные дают.

Answer (score 1):

В русском некогда существовало только числительное "четырьдесят".
"Сорок" же исходно - название меха или шкурки какого-то животного, вернее всего - соболя. 
Считали эти шкурки якобы четырьмя десятками. В конце концов именно такое количество шкурок стало называться "сОроком", позднее заменившим и само фонетически трудное числительное.

Answer (score 0):

Самый ранние примеры числительного **сорокъ** — в берестяной грамоте № 810 (40-70 XII) и в записи XIII в. из книжного текста — в Триоди XII—XIII вв. на л. 256.

Утверждение нового числительного по паронимической ассоциации могло быть поддержано **греческим** употреблением: *сорокадневный пост* (см. [Фасмер, III: 722]). По-видимому, взаимодействие с греческим созвучным словом имело разные источники. Оно могло быть воспринято русскими торговцами пушниной в конечном пункте торгового пути «из варяг в греки» на фоне славянского обозначения в системе числительных свойств предметов с постоянным составом, которое представляет **древнерусское** числительное *сорокъ*, отражающее бытовавший двадцатеричный счёт (40 = 20 + 20), восходящий к полному пальцевому счёту на пальцах рук и ног.

Письменные памятники склоняют к тому, чтобы видеть источник числительного *сорокъ* в существительном, обозначавшем связку пушнины из 40 шкурок. Такие связки использовались как товарно-денежные единицы и являлись важной приметой хозяйственно-бытовой жизни.

---

Похожая огласовка была обнаружена в ЕвГал 1266-1301 у существительного *сорокоустъ*, которое было заимствовано из греческого (*сороковой день после смерти*), но получило внутреннюю форму в результате сближения с древнерусскими лексемами *сорокъ*  и *уста*.

*По материалам Исторической грамматики древнерусского языка О.Ф. Жолобова 2006.*

Comment: Вообще-то Фасмер недвусмысленно ставит под сомнение связь с греческим источником. https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-12520.htm

Comment: Недвусмысленно сомневаться — это что-то с чем-то. Да и здесь видим не утверждение, а осторожное «могло быть».

Comment: Я не знаю, чего вы видите, но ссылаться нв Фасера в подтверждение своей версии - при том что Фасмер в ней сильно сомневается - как минимум непорядочно.