# Откуда появилось "сорок", и что оно означает?

Tags: значение-слов, значение

4 - четыре

14 - четырнадцать

40 - **сорок**

400 - четыреста

Почему "40" назвали именно "сорок", а не как-то иначе?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=сорок

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/28517/189475